# Loading of ScriptC script failed / cannot load library - Renderscript Android

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, renderscript

I get the following error message:

> 01-19 23:31:16.436: E/RenderScript(30603): Unable to open shared library (/data/data/com.example.android.rs.hellocompute//lib/librs.mono.so): Cannot load library: reloc_library[1313]:  1222 cannot locate '_Z9rsForEach9rs_script13rs_allocationS0_'...
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.436: E/RenderScript(30603): Unable to open system shared library (/system/lib/librs.mono.so): (null)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.444: D/AndroidRuntime(30603): Shutting down VM
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.444: W/dalvikvm(30603): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.rs.hellocompute/com.example.android.rs.hellocompute.HelloCompute}: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603): Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.(ScriptC.java:69)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at com.example.android.rs.hellocompute.ScriptC_mono.(ScriptC_mono.java:41)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at com.example.android.rs.hellocompute.HelloCompute.createScript(HelloCompute.java:64)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at com.example.android.rs.hellocompute.HelloCompute.onCreate(HelloCompute.java:49)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
>
> 01-19 23:31:16.585: E/AndroidRuntime(30603):   ... 11 more

I guess that this message is created by `int id` being 0 in ScriptC_mono.java although it should be `R.raw.mono`, but I cannot find out why. Here are my *.rs and MainActivity.java files:

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HelloCompute extends Activity {
private Bitmap mBitmapIn;
private Bitmap mBitmapOut;

private RenderScript mRS;
private Allocation mInAllocation;
private Allocation mOutAllocation;
private ScriptC_mono mScript;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mBitmapIn = loadBitmap(R.drawable.data);
    mBitmapOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmapIn.getWidth(), mBitmapIn.getHeight(),
                                     mBitmapIn.getConfig());

    ImageView in = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayin);
    in.setImageBitmap(mBitmapIn);

    ImageView out = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayout);

    createScript();
    out.setImageBitmap(mBitmapOut);
}


private void createScript() {
    mRS = RenderScript.create(this);

    mInAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, mBitmapIn,
                                                Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                                                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    mOutAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, mBitmapOut,
                                                 Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                                                 Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

    mScript = new ScriptC_mono(mRS, getResources(), R.raw.mono);

    mScript.forEach_root(mInAllocation, mOutAllocation);
    mOutAllocation.copyTo(mBitmapOut);

    mScript.destroy();
}

private Bitmap loadBitmap(int resource) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource, options);
}}
```

Mono.rs:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.android.example.hellocompute)

rs_allocation gIn;
rs_allocation gOut;
rs_script gScript;

const static float3 gMonoMult = {0.299f, 0.587f, 0.114f};

void root(const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out, const void *usrData, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
float4 f4 = rsUnpackColor8888(*v_in);

float3 mono = dot(f4.rgb, gMonoMult);
*v_out = rsPackColorTo8888(mono);
}

void filter() {
rsForEach(gScript, gIn, gOut, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

I simply used ScriptIntrinsic and modified a matrix with the specific red components using the method setColorMatrix(3fMatrix m) in ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix.

Thanks for all of your ideas, this works for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem that will be fixed in the next SDK release (many others have hit it due to missing rsForEach() and other functions).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there already a guess when it's gonna be released? And do you see an opportunity for the meantime, to get the App working? @StephenHines

Comment: There is no way to work around this issue currently. I can't share when the next SDK will be released, but they do ship updates/fixes quite often (almost monthly).

Comment: Ok, so I have to wait...nevertheless, Thank you!

Comment: @stephenHines looks like a new build tools version was just released.  Will this fix the issue above?

Comment: I believe it does fix this issue.

Comment: For me it didn't have an effect, I still get the same error messages... Nothing changes even when I try to build a complete new project following the instructions! @StephenHines

Comment: Your problem is that you are not matching the Application package name and the one specified in the .rs pragma. Make sure those match exactly, or it can fail to load when we need to re-use the cache/ directory.

Comment: Actually, you're right; this was wrong. Thing is, that the error still occurs in the same way after fixing the mistake! So no solution yet... @StephenHines